# Returning the return value from inner function to parent function- Javascript, Dynamics crm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

Will the below code return the boolean value from the innner function to the parent function displayButton()? The parent function is called on click of a button in dynamics CRM. The function should return a boolean value depending if the a case is selected and the selected is active or resolve.

```
   //function called on click of a button in ms crm. 
    function displayButton()
    {
        var Obj = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid");
        var ObjValue = Obj.getValue();
        //parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(" Value: " + ObjValue);
        if (ObjValue == null)
            return false;
        //else
        //    parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(" Hi");

        var EntityType = ObjValue[0].entityType;

        var Guid = ObjValue[0].id;
        var id = Guid.slice(1, -1);
        //parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(" Guid: " + id);

//Checking if regarding field is selected a case lookup value
        if (EntityType == "incident")
        {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/incidents(" + id + ")?$select=statecode", true);
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");

            req.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (this.readyState === 4)
                {

                    req.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status === 200)
                    {

                        debugger;
                        var result = JSON.parse(this.response);

//checking if selected case is active or resolved.
                        var statecode = result["statecode"];

                        var statecode_formatted = result["statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                        if (statecode_formatted == "Active") {
                            return true;

                        }
                        else if (statecode_formatted == "Resolved")
                            return false;
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Zero");
                    }


                }

            };
            req.send();

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you want to access the value returned by your asynchronous `XmlHttpRequest`, either you'll need to put your logic in the `if (this.status === 200)` scope or provide a callback.

Your `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous because of the `true` parameter in this line:

```
req.open("GET", parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/incidents(" + id + ")?$select=statecode", true);
```

To provide a callback, separate out your code into two functions:

```
function getCaseState(id, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/incidents(" + id + ")?$select=statecode", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");

    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
                var statecode = result["statecode"];
                var statecode_formatted = result["statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];

                callback(statecode_formatted);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Then call `getCaseState`, passing it the `id` of your incident and a function to call once the request is ready:

```
// called on click of a button in CRM. 
function displayButton() {
    var regarding = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();
    var entityType = regarding[0].entityType;
    var regardingId = regarding[0].id.slice(1, -1);

    // Check if regarding is an active case.
    if (entityType == "incident") {
        getCaseState(regardingId, function(state) {
            var isActive = state === "Active";

            if (isActive) {
                // TODO
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The function passed in the code above is anonymous -- you should separate it out further and name it.

Comment: This too is not working. isActive variable contains value true or false, but it does not return true or false to parent function. I wrote it as 

if (isActive) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
This does not return true or false to displayButton function.

Comment: It won't work as you expect it to work. This is why my answer and the other answer to your question are both **no**: you cannot return the result from your asynchronous request to your parent function. If you want to work with the result from your inner function, you must use a callback. If `displayButton` itself is not the parent function but also has a parent function then pass the callback initially into `displayButton` and then into `getCaseState`. And if `displayButton` is the parent function then you are already working with the `isActive` result and don't need to use `return true`.

Comment: displayButton is the parent function. I returned isActive by writing:
getCaseState(regardingId, function(state) {
            var isActive = state === "Active";
        return isActive            
        });
The button on the crm ribbon is dependent on displayButton return value. But the button is being displayed even if Case is resolved. As isActive is false when case is resolved, the button should not be displayed.

Comment: It sounds like if you want to pursue this route for your requirement, you want a synchronous request. This can be achieved by changing `true` to `false` in your `req.open` line. Better yet, I think you want to create an enable rule for the ribbon button using the [Ribbon Workbench](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I created a enable rule in Ribbon Workbench and displayButton function is called from there. Also, changed it to false in req.open line. But it is not working. The button hides if I select any other entity than case and gets displayed if I select any case. But I also have to check whether the selected case is Active or not. Button should get displayed only if the selected case is Active.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**. The inner function gets defined and assigned to `req.onreadystatechange`. `displayButton()` never calls the inner function. So it won't be executed in this context and therefore won't return a value.

Probably the this could be a good dig deeper into functions in JS: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

Comment: Thanks. How can I edit it to return value depending on the case is active or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have pasted way too much code. This is Stack Overflow, you should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
The only way to do that without changing your code too much would be to change your request to synchronous as suggested already and assign result to some variable defined outside of the callback. Something like that:

```
function displayButton(){
    var result = false; //or true, depends what you want as default
    //some code
    //change it to synchonous request!!

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/incidents(" + id + ")?$select=statecode", false);
    //...
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
         if (this.readyState === 4) {
             req.onreadystatechange = null;
             if (this.status === 200) {
                  //ommiting more code to get to the clue
                  //...
                  //...
                  if (statecode_formatted == "Active") {
                        result = true;
                    }
                    else if (statecode_formatted == "Resolved")
                        result = false;
                    else {
                        result = false;
                  }
             }
         }
     };
     req.send();

     return result;       
}
```

I don't want to change your whole code, because you pasted way too much of it, but I'm sure you've got the idea. As suggested in another answer, you should move your calling function to a separate funtion with callback and assign your "result" in this callback. Callback will be run synchronously, so the function will return your "result" with proper value.

Answer (score 0):

Your **XMLHttpRequest** is **asynchronous** here. So you *can not get Response immediately* so execution *will not end immediately*.

i solved this problem using

```
setTimeout(function () {

  },550);
```

*i think u can try in following way.*

here change i did is i kept **XMLHttpRequest** in separate *function* i.e, **getResult(id)** and calling that *function from parent function* i.e, **displayButton()**.

And insted of *returning* value from child function, i'm *setting that Boolean value to Global variable* i.e, **var boolValue;**

And in parent function *before returning a value* i'm waiting for 550 mil sec
, *so that **asynchronous** execution gets over*.

below is the code snippet.

**Parent function**

```
var boolValue;

//function called on click of a button in ms crm. 
function displayButton() {
    var Obj = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid");
    var ObjValue = Obj.getValue();
    //parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(" Value: " + ObjValue);
    if (ObjValue == null)
        return false;
    //else
    //    parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(" Hi");

    var EntityType = ObjValue[0].entityType;

    var Guid = ObjValue[0].id;
    var id = Guid.slice(1, -1);
    //parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(" Guid: " + id);

    //Checking if regarding field is selected a case lookup value
    if (EntityType == "incident") {
        getResult(id);

        setTimeout(function () {
            if(boolValue == true || boolValue == false)
            {
                return boolValue;
            }
        }, 550);

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }


}
```

**child function**

```
function getResult(id)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/incidents(" + id + ")?$select=statecode", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");

    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {

            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.response);

                //checking if selected case is active or resolved.
                var statecode = result["statecode"];

                var statecode_formatted = result["statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                if (statecode_formatted == "Active") {
                    boolValue = true;
                }
                else if (statecode_formatted == "Resolved")
                    boolValue = false;
                else {
                    boolValue = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Zero");
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

This way solved my problem.